# mongo db findOne and $or does order of arguments matters or hierarchy? [performance]

Tags: python, mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, pymongo

I mean for example while having two conditions: if first condition true will it avoid checking the second?

```
doc = collection.find_one(
    {'$or': [
              {
               'k': kind,
               'i': int(pk)
              },
              {
               'children.k': kind, 
               'children.i': int(pk)
              }

            ]
    }, { '_id': False})
```

I would like that it stops further searching when matching first condition, so it not goes lower level to search around children.

Is it matter of arguments order in `$OR` closure or rather mongodb knows smartly the hierarchy and it influences order of search by `findOne`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the order matters which is one strong reason for an array form of arguments which of course is ordered.

So basically this is referred to as "short circuit" evaluation. So only where the first condition does not match then is the next condition tested and so on.

So can best demonstrate with a collection like this:

```js
{ "a": 1 },
{ "a": 2, "b": 1 }
```

And then the following query:

```js
db.collection.find({ "$or": [ { "a": 1 }, { "b": 1 } ] })
```

Which of course finds both documents since even though the first does not have an element for "b" the first condition is met anyway. In the second document since the first failed then the second was used to match.

Comment: This is only true for the collection scan case.  As @sammaye says in his answer, if an index can be used for both clauses, the two `$or` queries are separately executed with their results merged.  In that case, the clause order doesn't matter.

Comment: I can't see any documentation suggesting the clause order is guaranteed regardless of COLLSCAN vs IXSCAN; are you able to share the source?

Comment: It looks like MongoDB sorts clauses alphabetically so I'm pretty certain this answer is incorrect https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-45308 -- basically there's no short circuit evaluation, all clause will be executed and if limiting by 1, a document from any clause may be returned (most like one that starts with 'a' )

Answer (score 4):

> I would like that it stops further searching when matchin first condition, so it not goes lower level to search around children.

The question you have to ask yourself is: How can MongoDB know how both sides of the `$or` are satisfied by one side? How does MongoDB know that the documents that do not satisfy the first condition do not satisfy the second?

If I were to say that I have a set of documents, half with `{a:1,b:1}` and half with `{b:2}` how can you know that `a:1 OR b:1` is satisfied by the first half if you have no idea what the second half look like?

Simple answer is that it doesn't. It has to search both conditions (via parallel queries which are then returned and duplicates merged) as such order does not really matter unless it were an `$and` and in this case the importance of order is in the index not the query as the query will be moved around to optimise for quickest path to results.

So in reality the way MongoDB works is that it shoots off a "query" per condition. This actually explains the behaviour: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#behaviors

> When using indexes with $or queries, each clause of an $or can use its own index.

Comment: Although as you say mongodb queries each clause in parallel, will it still respect clause order when limiting to a single document. That is to say
if the first clause returns a document, is it guaranteed to return that document, or is there a risk it'd return a document from another clause instead?

Comment: @riscarrott Hmm, I am not entirety sure the execution order of $or is guaranteed in response, only a person coding that would be able to tell you, but I also would not rely on it even if they said yes, however, it will execute all clauses which means while it will pick up that document and other documents all at the same time, so if a document exists in one clause while being excluded in another it will still return that document, same with documents that are mutually exclusive but clauses return both

Comment: Yeh makes sense; I can actually see now that the `parsedQuery` from explain() alphabetises the clauses so `$or: [{ a: 1 }, { c: 1 }, { b: 1 }]` becomes `$or: [{ a: 1 }, { b: 1 }, { c: 1 }]` so yeh, definitely shouldn't rely on the order. Thanks.